# Secure image upload in php

Tags: php, image, security, upload

I am making an image upload function which I can re-use in my code, which has to be 100% secure. Please tell me if you can spot and security holes in my initial code;

```
function Upload($file)
{
    list($width,$height,$type,$attr) = getimagesize($file);
    $mime = image_type_to_mime_type($type);
    
    if(($mime != "image/jpeg") && ($mime != "image/pjpeg") && ($mime != "image/png")) 
    {
        return 'Error3: Upload file type un-recognized. Only .JPG or .PNG images allowed';
    }else{
        $Newname = md5('sillysalt'.time());
        if (move_uploaded_file($file, 'images/'.$Newname.$type)) 
        {
            return 'Uploaded!';
        }else{
            return 'Server Error!';
        } 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** This is how far I've gotten with your help and some research, please tell me what you think. I don't mind much about the speed, for me it's all about being 100% secure, or as close to.

```
function Upload($file)
{
    list($width,$height,$type,$attr) = getimagesize($file);
    $mime = image_type_to_mime_type($type);
    $folder = 'images/';
    
    // mime checks add a layer of security that keeps out less sophisticated attackers 
    if(($mime != "image/jpeg") && ($mime != "image/pjpeg") && ($mime != "image/png")) 
    {
        return 'Error3: Upload file type un-recognized. Only .JPG or .PNG images allowed';
    }else{
        // If the file has no width its not a valid image
        if(!$width)
        {
            $Newname = md5('sillysalt'.time());
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $mime2 = finfo_file($finfo, $folder.$Newname);
            
            // Should I remove this second mime check? since the info comes form the same spoofable source in the image
            if(($mime != "image/jpeg") && ($mime != "image/pjpeg") && ($mime != "image/png")) 
            {
                $fileType = exif_imagetype($file);
                $allowed = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);
                if(!in_array($fileType, $allowed))
                {
                    // don't overwrite an existing file
                    $i = 0;
                    $parts = pathinfo($file);
                    while(file_exists($folder . $name))
                    {
                        $i++;
                        $name = $Newname."-".$i.".".$parts["extension"];
                    }
    
                    if(move_uploaded_file($file, $folder.$name)) 
                    {
                        // set good permissions for the file
                        chmod($name, 0644);
                        return 'Uploaded!';
                    }else{
                        return 'Server Error!';
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "100% secure" mean?

Comment: as in only accept these three types of images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't use the `FileInfo` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) extensions from php to check the mime type, your function is not secure at all (think later you'll want to upload pdf's, excels, etc).
Also, md5 over md5 does nothing than increasing the collision chances.

L.E: **Something as simple as the following should do it:**

```
function getExtensionToMimeTypeMapping() {
    return array(
        'ai'=>'application/postscript',
        'aif'=>'audio/x-aiff',
        'aifc'=>'audio/x-aiff',
        'aiff'=>'audio/x-aiff',
        'anx'=>'application/annodex',
        'asc'=>'text/plain',
        'au'=>'audio/basic',
        'avi'=>'video/x-msvideo',
        'axa'=>'audio/annodex',
        'axv'=>'video/annodex',
        'bcpio'=>'application/x-bcpio',
        'bin'=>'application/octet-stream',
        'bmp'=>'image/bmp',
        'c'=>'text/plain',
        'cc'=>'text/plain',
        'ccad'=>'application/clariscad',
        'cdf'=>'application/x-netcdf',
        'class'=>'application/octet-stream',
        'cpio'=>'application/x-cpio',
        'cpt'=>'application/mac-compactpro',
        'csh'=>'application/x-csh',
        'css'=>'text/css',
        'csv'=>'text/csv',
        'dcr'=>'application/x-director',
        'dir'=>'application/x-director',
        'dms'=>'application/octet-stream',
        'doc'=>'application/msword',
        'drw'=>'application/drafting',
        'dvi'=>'application/x-dvi',
        'dwg'=>'application/acad',
        'dxf'=>'application/dxf',
        'dxr'=>'application/x-director',
        'eps'=>'application/postscript',
        'etx'=>'text/x-setext',
        'exe'=>'application/octet-stream',
        'ez'=>'application/andrew-inset',
        'f'=>'text/plain',
        'f90'=>'text/plain',
        'flac'=>'audio/flac',
        'fli'=>'video/x-fli',
        'flv'=>'video/x-flv',
        'gif'=>'image/gif',
        'gtar'=>'application/x-gtar',
        'gz'=>'application/x-gzip',
        'h'=>'text/plain',
        'hdf'=>'application/x-hdf',
        'hh'=>'text/plain',
        'hqx'=>'application/mac-binhex40',
        'htm'=>'text/html',
        'html'=>'text/html',
        'ice'=>'x-conference/x-cooltalk',
        'ief'=>'image/ief',
        'iges'=>'model/iges',
        'igs'=>'model/iges',
        'ips'=>'application/x-ipscript',
        'ipx'=>'application/x-ipix',
        'jpe'=>'image/jpeg',
        'jpeg'=>'image/jpeg',
        'jpg'=>'image/jpeg',
        'js'=>'application/x-javascript',
        'kar'=>'audio/midi',
        'latex'=>'application/x-latex',
        'lha'=>'application/octet-stream',
        'lsp'=>'application/x-lisp',
        'lzh'=>'application/octet-stream',
        'm'=>'text/plain',
        'man'=>'application/x-troff-man',
        'me'=>'application/x-troff-me',
        'mesh'=>'model/mesh',
        'mid'=>'audio/midi',
        'midi'=>'audio/midi',
        'mif'=>'application/vnd.mif',
        'mime'=>'www/mime',
        'mov'=>'video/quicktime',
        'movie'=>'video/x-sgi-movie',
        'mp2'=>'audio/mpeg',
        'mp3'=>'audio/mpeg',
        'mpe'=>'video/mpeg',
        'mpeg'=>'video/mpeg',
        'mpg'=>'video/mpeg',
        'mpga'=>'audio/mpeg',
        'ms'=>'application/x-troff-ms',
        'msh'=>'model/mesh',
        'nc'=>'application/x-netcdf',
        'oga'=>'audio/ogg',
        'ogg'=>'audio/ogg',
        'ogv'=>'video/ogg',
        'ogx'=>'application/ogg',
        'oda'=>'application/oda',
        'pbm'=>'image/x-portable-bitmap',
        'pdb'=>'chemical/x-pdb',
        'pdf'=>'application/pdf',
        'pgm'=>'image/x-portable-graymap',
        'pgn'=>'application/x-chess-pgn',
        'png'=>'image/png',
        'pnm'=>'image/x-portable-anymap',
        'pot'=>'application/mspowerpoint',
        'ppm'=>'image/x-portable-pixmap',
        'pps'=>'application/mspowerpoint',
        'ppt'=>'application/mspowerpoint',
        'ppz'=>'application/mspowerpoint',
        'pre'=>'application/x-freelance',
        'prt'=>'application/pro_eng',
        'ps'=>'application/postscript',
        'qt'=>'video/quicktime',
        'ra'=>'audio/x-realaudio',
        'ram'=>'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
        'ras'=>'image/cmu-raster',
        'rgb'=>'image/x-rgb',
        'rm'=>'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
        'roff'=>'application/x-troff',
        'rpm'=>'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin',
        'rtf'=>'text/rtf',
        'rtx'=>'text/richtext',
        'scm'=>'application/x-lotusscreencam',
        'set'=>'application/set',
        'sgm'=>'text/sgml',
        'sgml'=>'text/sgml',
        'sh'=>'application/x-sh',
        'shar'=>'application/x-shar',
        'silo'=>'model/mesh',
        'sit'=>'application/x-stuffit',
        'skd'=>'application/x-koan',
        'skm'=>'application/x-koan',
        'skp'=>'application/x-koan',
        'skt'=>'application/x-koan',
        'smi'=>'application/smil',
        'smil'=>'application/smil',
        'snd'=>'audio/basic',
        'sol'=>'application/solids',
        'spl'=>'application/x-futuresplash',
        'spx'=>'audio/ogg',
        'src'=>'application/x-wais-source',
        'step'=>'application/STEP',
        'stl'=>'application/SLA',
        'stp'=>'application/STEP',
        'sv4cpio'=>'application/x-sv4cpio',
        'sv4crc'=>'application/x-sv4crc',
        'swf'=>'application/x-shockwave-flash',
        't'=>'application/x-troff',
        'tar'=>'application/x-tar',
        'tcl'=>'application/x-tcl',
        'tex'=>'application/x-tex',
        'texi'=>'application/x-texinfo',
        'texinfo'=>'application/x-texinfo',
        'tif'=>'image/tiff',
        'tiff'=>'image/tiff',
        'tr'=>'application/x-troff',
        'tsi'=>'audio/TSP-audio',
        'tsp'=>'application/dsptype',
        'tsv'=>'text/tab-separated-values',
        'txt'=>'text/plain',
        'unv'=>'application/i-deas',
        'ustar'=>'application/x-ustar',
        'vcd'=>'application/x-cdlink',
        'vda'=>'application/vda',
        'viv'=>'video/vnd.vivo',
        'vivo'=>'video/vnd.vivo',
        'vrml'=>'model/vrml',
        'wav'=>'audio/x-wav',
        'wrl'=>'model/vrml',
        'xbm'=>'image/x-xbitmap',
        'xlc'=>'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'xll'=>'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'xlm'=>'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'xls'=>'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'xlw'=>'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'xml'=>'application/xml',
        'xpm'=>'image/x-xpixmap',
        'xspf'=>'application/xspf+xml',
        'xwd'=>'image/x-xwindowdump',
        'xyz'=>'chemical/x-pdb',
        'zip'=>'application/zip',
    );
}

function getMimeType($filePath) {

    if (!is_file($filePath)) {
        return false;
    }

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);
    finfo_close($finfo);

    return $mime;
}

function upload($filePath, $destinationDir = 'images', array $allowedMimes = array()) {

    if (!is_file($filePath) || !is_dir($destinationDir)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!($mime = getMimeType($filePath))) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!in_array($mime, $allowedMimes)) {
        return false;
    }

    $ext = null;
    $extMapping = getExtensionToMimeTypeMapping();
    foreach ($extMapping as $extension => $mimeType) {
        if ($mimeType == $mime) {
            $ext = $extension;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (empty($ext)) {
        $ext = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    }

    if (empty($ext)) {
        return false;
    }

    $fileName = md5(uniqid(rand(0, time()), true)) . '.' . $ext;
    $newFilePath = $destinationDir.'/'.$fileName;

    if(!rename($filePath, $newFilePath)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $fileName;
}

// use it 
if (isset($_FILES['something']['tmp_name'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['something']['tmp_name'];
    $storagePath = 'images'; // this is relative to this script, better use absolute path.
    $allowedMimes = array('image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif', 'image/pjpeg');

    $fileName = upload($file, $storagePath, $allowedMimes);
    if (!$fileName) {
        exit ('Your file type is not allowed.');
    } else {
         // check if file is image, optional, in case you allow multiple types of files.
         // $imageInfo = @getimagesize($storagePath.'/'.$fileName);
        exit ("Your uploaded file is {$fileName} and can be found at {$storagePath}/{$fileName}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to write something similar.

Comment: -1 PHP code can be embedded into various other data types. You need to check the file’s extension as it’s that information that the web server uses when deciding how to handle a requested file.

Comment: I've looked at all your comments, and revised my code, please review it again and tell me what you think!

Comment: once again, for the last time, the mimes from $_FILES can be faked, not the ones from fileinfo, and as you can see the code above relies on fileinfo only to check if the mime type of the given file is correct or not.

Comment: Will this also protect my server from code embedded in the image itself?

Comment: yes, it will. As a side note -- That's the reason php's team developed fileinfo, to make sure a file is indeed what it pretend it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, `tmp_name` does not have a name extension.

Comment: @Gumbo now that's a nice catch. Thanks, i updated the code to fix the issue.

Comment: the following is a quote from the php manual about the fileinfo function 'While this is not a bullet proof approach the heuristics used do a very good job'. Guess its not quite the silver bullet all developers hope for :(

Comment: @Thejoker123 you won't get better than that.

Comment: You still try to get the name extension from `tmp_name` with `pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`.

Comment: @Gumbo - yes unless the extension cannot be found in the array of extensions to mimes. The reason why i left that there is because maybe he wants to use it on other files, not just from tmp where they have no extension as you pointed out.(think at some file fetched via curl for example, written to a temp location and checked against)

Comment: @Twisted1919 The function says `upload`, and it uses [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file), which only works for actually uploaded files. Using this function for files other than uploaded files won’t work.

Comment: @Gumbo `rename` it is then :)

Comment: @Twisted1919 You don’t get it, do you? `move_uploaded_files` does only work with actually uploaded files as it compares the given file path with a list of paths of uploaded files, i.e., the `tmp_name` values. So it *cannot* be used with other files.

Answer (score 0):

Stop filtering it by mime type it is not safe!

Client can send different mime types with different file extensions. So, you need to check file extension.

edit:

I think I have been misunderstood, I wrote the answer to tell that checking mime type to determine file type is not a good way, the best way to determine the file type is checking file extension. So, I don't mean that checking file extension is enough. Either checking only file extension or mime type is not safe way.

What to do?
1-Check mime type

2-Check file extension

3- decode file name

4- check file content consistency (if possible)

5- regenerate file content (if possible)

I know that attackers can bypass first and second way by using "null byte hack" and "mime type bypass"

So, 3,4 and 5 is so important for security.

Comment: what if I have an evil.php and I rename it to evil.png? If you check only the extension, then you will believe it is really a png?

Comment: @fobus - that's just plain dangerous advice. if you did it, just go and fix your files asap.

Comment: @Twisted1919 why do you think that cheking mime type is secure? Client can by pass it.

Comment: @LajosArpad if I send PHP file with an extension image/png will you believe that that is a png file?

Comment: no it can't! when using fileinfo extension, PHP uses the operating system to determine the mime type of a file. IS NOT the same mime type that you get from $_FILES. the mime type from $_FILES is not to be trusted, as it can report wrong value.

Comment: @fobus, I might believe it, but FileInfo will not. That is why I upvoted Twisted1919's answer and am thinking about downvoting this answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad The server will only consult the file’s extension: if it’s `.php`, it will send the file through PHP; if it’s `.png`, it will send the file to the client.

Comment: @Twisted1919 PHP code can be easily hidden in a valid PNG or other image format, either in special segments for comments or similar or directly in the image data. Here’s an [excellent example of a PHP shell inside an PNG that even withstands the re-encoding used by PNG](https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2012/06/encoding-web-shells-in-png-idat-chunks/).

Comment: @fobus +1 That’s the only way to go!

Comment: @Gumbo i'll leave it with your idea because clearly not you nor @ fobus have a clue about this. eventually you will understand my point, and if you don't, then i wouldn't want to be one of your customers :)

Comment: I've looked at all your comments, and revised my code, please review it again and tell me what you think!

Comment: @Twisted1919 I’ll understand your point that the information the client sends cannot be trusted. But this does not only apply for the media type but also for the file name. And when it comes to serving a file, it’s the file’s name extension that counts. So *you* better check that as well.

Comment: @Gumbo with proper headers i can make the server send whatever i want therefore NO, is not the extension that matters.

Comment: @Twisted1919 What “proper headers” are you referring to?

Comment: like `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php `. it was just an example so that you can see what i mean. I think you can also do it with `header()` function, when a `.png` is required for instance, to fake it into actually read php code (didn't try though).

Comment: @Twisted1919 That ‘header’, as you call it, is an Apache HTTPD directive that tells it to handle files with the name extension `.php` as `application/x-httpd-php`. Then on the other side, there is a handler, probably mod_php, which registers itself with Apache HTTPD with this handler name. This basically tells Apache HTTPD that any file ending with `.php` should be handled by PHP. That’s exactly what I meant by saying it depends on the file name extension. And unless you do the same for `.png`, such files, where there is no handler registerd, are simply sent to the client.

Comment: @Gumbo clearly you didn't get what i wrote. it was just an example for serving one content type with the content of the other just based on extension(when i said header i had in mind the php header method, clearly not the best example). Anyway, earlier i said i am going to stop with this discussion as it goes nowhere. I will never trust a file by it's extension, if you do, it's just your problem.

Comment: @Twisted1919 Serving files and uploading files is completely different. Why are you talking about serving files when this question is clearly about uploading files? Anyway, I didn’t say I trust a file by it’s name extension. I just don’t trust a file by it’s media type, whether provided by the user or detected by [some magic pattern matching, which your *FileInfo* solution is](http://php.net/intro.fileinfo). Both can easily be forged.