# Check File is zip type before upload

Tags: php

I want people to be able to upload zip files to my server. I have a form for them to upload to and it redirects to an upload page. I can successfully upload pictures (png and jpg) but whenever I try a zip I canot upload it, its not show me any error, Is there a way to accept the zip files?

```
<?php
function uploadfile()
{
    $allowedExts = array("zip", "rar");
    $split = explode(".",$_FILES["filework"]["name"]);    
    $type = strtolower($split[sizeof($split)-1]); 
    $rname = time().".".$type;

    if (($_FILES["filework"]["type"] == "application/zip") || ($_FILES["filework"]["type"] == "application/x-zip") || ($_FILES["filework"]["type"] == "application/x-zip-compressed") && ($_FILES["filework"]["size"] < 20000000) && in_array($split, $allowedExts)) {
        $destination = "uploads/".$rname;
        $temp_file = $_FILES['filework']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($temp_file,$destination);
        return $rname;
    } else {
        return $_FILES["filework"]["error"];}
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You cannot check something serverside before you upload it.

Comment: @DanFromGermany No, I need check it befor upload it, its work with me for Docs,doc,jpg, png .... else zip file why !!!

Comment: Some hosting services do not allow uploading (or renaming to) of 'zip' files. Especially the 'free' ones. This actually makes sense as it can lead to 'abuse' of the service. You may need to review the 'terms of service' where it will state which file types they will store and under what conditions.

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/17582046/ which I once tested some time ago. If that doesn't work, then as Ryan's comment states; it could be a restriction set by your hosting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
in_array($type, $allowedExts)
```

also, nothing will be returned if your `if` fails and no actual error is generated, see [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

And as DanFromGermany said the process of upload is as follows:

1. user sends the form with the selected file
2. server loads the file to a temp folder (that's why you need `$temp_file = $_FILES['filework']['tmp_name'];`)
3. server executes php script to render the `action` page of the form

Because your php is executed last, it cannot check for file extension prior to upload, however you can just ignore the temp file if it doesn't meet criteria.